# Polygon-edge premined Account Balance Is Zero

Tags: polygon

Actually, I have my private chain based on polygon-edge technology, but when I added my private network to meta mask wallet, my pre-mined account balance was showing zero one more thing, when I query my chain about balance, it returns me the exact balance, which I pre-mined. Please provide your valuable suggestions if you guys can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge the Premine Balance is taken in wei so If you wanna 1000 Native Token in your wallet, you need to enter 1000000000000000000000 in the ccommand

```
polygon-edge genesis ibft ------  premine=0x95E6ABA28711BBfAFf8bE754836EBc6E7eeDBfe4:100000000000000000000
```

This Will Premine 1000 Native Coin in the wallet 0x95E6ABA28711BBfAFf8bE754836EBc6E7eeDBfe4

Comment: Thanks Noooblien For you help buddy
Worked for me

Comment: Welcome Akshay 
Kindly mark it as an answer it will other person who will facing the same issue 